# BSODs while unattended and MBR issues

Tags: windows-7, laptop, ssd, bsod, mbr

This is a slightly long preface:

I just bought an OCZ 120gb Agility 3 SSD for my Dell XPS 15 (L501X). Installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 Professional, had no issues for about a day or 2.

After doing some windows updates and installing some programs and a regular session of computering, I rebooted to finish the updates, etc. On boot, I had a black screen after login. I checked the processes (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC to the task manager) and explorer.exe wasn't running, tried to run it and it shut itself back down. At this point I'm worried. I reboot again, same result. I pull out my USB drive I used to install Windows 7, try a repair, but the repair tool said it couldn't find an OS. What? I reboot again, but this time, I get a missing MBR error.

I rebooted a few more times, same result in the repair, no OS found. I was able to copy files to and from my SSD through the driver open explorer window, so the SSD is still fine. I tried swapping USB ports to see if it made a difference, and this time it did find my OS. I tried a repair, it said it worked. I restart my computer and still get the missing MBR error. I tried to boot from the USB again to try and fix it, but instead of booting the install menu, it now boots into windows from my USB. So apparently it put the MBR on my USB drive... I'm stuck booting with my USB drive for now. I can deal with that for now since I'm using my laptop as a desktop replacement.

My future plan is to replace my DVD drive with my old HDD. I just received the drive caddy, so I'm ready to do that soon. But before I do, I want to fix this MBR problem. Any ideas? How can I get rid of the MBR on my USB drive so I can start booting into the install disk again?

Now for the BSOD issue. I get random BSODs when I leave it on and go to work.

Here are my 4 most recent minidumps, zipped: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2251907/072012-13884-01.zip

I don't know what to make of the BSODs, I don't have much experience in that field. Any info would be helpful. How can I solve these?

Thanks

Comment: I've answered about your crashes. Could you post the MBR problem as a seperate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use bluescreenview to check dumps people send to me - for 'local' debugging, use [whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed/) - its a lot more readable than anything else I've tried. BSV gives google searches, and i'll add that to my answer if you want to do further digging at the end

Loading the minidumps into [bluescreen view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), I find three classes of blue screen. One of the issues your having is with the wireless network driver - according to [this thread,](http://www.sevenforums.com/crashes-debugging/107797-win-7-x64-bsod-bad_pool_caller.html) installing a newer driver for your wireless card should fix the blue screens related to 
NETw5s64.sys.

You have also had a blue screen to do with nvoclk64.sys - uninstalling ntune will fix that according to this thread.

The plain old ntokernel crash, i can't trace, unfortunately

Bluescreen View Searches if you want to dig further.

[Network Driver Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=BAD_POOL_CALLER%20NETw5s64.sys)

[Nvidia Crash google](http://www.google.com/search?q=SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION%20nvoclk64.sys)

[Ntokernel search](http://www.google.com/search?q=DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE%20ntoskrnl.exe)